# Looking to remove text from text file using powershell

Tags: powershell, replace, command-line

I'm trying to edit a large **plain text** document containing various html elements such as the following:

- `<p> & </p>`
- `<script> & </script>`
- `<style> & </style>`
- `<div> & </div>`
- And in more extreme cases; `<span style="color: #ff0000;"> & </span>`

My goal is to remove any `<UniqueText>` from a text file. I've not worked with powershell much so my knowledge is limited, none less, I gave it a shot.

For replacing all `<UniqueText>`

```
get-content "C:\Users\John\Desktop\input.txt" | -replace "\<.*?\>","" | Out-File C:\Users\John\Desktop\output.txt
```

The above script gives the following error:

> -replace : The term '-replace' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: Try `... | % {$_ -replace "\<.*?\>",""} | ...` instead.

Comment: `(Get-Content FILE) -replace '\<.*?\>'`

Comment: Are you removing HTML tags from an otherwise plain text file, or are you removing tags from an actual HTML file? For the latter I'd recommend using a proper HTML parser.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers It's a plain text file. Sorry, should have stated that in the post.

Comment: @Paxz That worked like a charm. If you make a post containing that response I will mark it as solved.

Comment: @JohnKens Yeah I wrote an answer with an explanation of both solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `-replace` you have to be sure that you parse the string correctly to the call.
There are two ways you can solve your problem:

**1.** Use foreach to go through each line of the file and use `-replace` on each line (this might be helpfull if you want to do something else with the lines):

```
get-content "C:\Users\John\Desktop\input.txt" | % {$_ -replace "\<.*?\>",""} | Out-File C:\Users\John\Desktop\output.txt
```

`%` is the alias for `foreach`

`$_` is element of the `foreach`, so each line of the file

**2.** Use replace on the file without going through each line:

```
(get-content "C:\Users\John\Desktop\input.txt") -replace "\<.*?\>","" |  Out-File C:\Users\John\Desktop\output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

i use this command

```
Get-Content C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts | % {$_ -replace "some text","" -replace "some text",""} |Out-File C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

but the file become empty.